# Revit Addin Visual Studio Calling SOAP web service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autodesk, revit-api

Creating a Autodesk Revit addin.
I want it to be able to talk to SOAP Web Services

The addin is created as a Class Library.
The SOAP client code is generated by using the Visual Studio Service Reference and pointing at the wsdl url.

When I launch the Addin from Revit I get the following error

Revit encountered a System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find endpoint element with name '{xxx}' and contract '{yyy}' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.

Note1 that the SOAP calls work fine if I create the Visual Studio Project as a command line Project and run it directly.

Note2 the build folder which I point to in the addin manifest has a .config file in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<RevitAddIns>
  <AddIn Type="Command">
<Name>AIMRevitTestTwo</Name>
<Assembly>
  C:\Users\greg.bluntzer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AIMRevitTestTwo\AIMRevitTestTwo\bin\Debug\AIMRevitTestTwo.dll
</Assembly>
<AddInId>604b1052-f742-4951-8576-c261d1993109</AddInId>
<FullClassName>App</FullClassName>
<VendorId>xxx</VendorId>
<VendorDescription>yyy</VendorDescription>
```

Is there something else I need to configure in my Visual Studio Project or Revit Manifest so that it will look at the .config file.

Update:  I found this [link](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/12/web-service.html)  That says to try and create/update the revit.exe.config file and add the bindings to that. It resolves my issue locally.That is not a good solution for me as I want to distribute this addin. So I still would like to know a way of making the addin so that it can read the config file that comes with the class library.

SOLUTION: as suggested I build the config information in the code

```
         <binding name="findAePReqEByDocumentSoapBinding"  allowCookies="true">
              <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic" realm="fmax" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </binding>
```

Turns into

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        binding.AllowCookies = true;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;
        binding.Security.Transport.Realm = "fmax";
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
        binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;

        EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress(DataAccess.END_POINT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the best answer in my experience is to create your bindings programmatically, rather than with a config file.

If you look at the constructor for your auto-generated SOAP client class, it has a no-argument constructor that you're probably using (which reads from the config) - but there's probably another one where you specify the address and the binding in the code. Go that route. Check out something like the [BasicHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Everything that is specified in the config can be added to that class in code.